# Django Limit ManytoMany queryset based on selected FK

Tags: django, django-admin

I have a model that looks like this:

```
class Invite(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event)
    roles = models.ManyToManyField(Role, blank=True, null=True)
    sent =  models.BooleanField("Invite Sent", default=False, editable=False)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"%s" % self.user

    class Meta:
        unique_together =(('user','event'),)


class Role(models.Model):
    """
    This associates a user's role to an event
    """
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event, related_name="roles")
    roletype = models.ForeignKey(RoleType)
    profiles = models.ManyToManyField(Profile, related_name="roles",
            blank=True, null=True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

So whenever a new Event is created, a bunch of roles gets created along with it. In the Invite model, how can I only show the roles associated with the event I've selected in the change form within Django Admin instead of showing all the entries in the Role model?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You want to dynamically filter the choices of the `roles` `choices`, so you will need `ajax` to perform this task.

Here's how you can make this work..

**1:** `OnChange` of the `event` send the `event_id` to your custom `view` through `ajax`.

**2:** From the `Roles` model `filter` based on the `event_id` you got from the `ajax` request and return the filtered `roles` by `serializing` into `JSON`.

**3:** Clear the existing `roles` and repopulate by parsing through the `JSON` response.

Eg:
This a `jquery` `getJSON` example

**javascript:**

```
$("#event").change(function (){         
 var event_id = $(this).val();              
    $.getJSON("/my-app/my-roles-filter-view/"+ event_id +"/",function(data){
        var roles_dd = $("#roles");
        $('#event >option').remove();
        $.each(data, function(index,value) {
        roles_dd.append($("<option />").val(value).text(value));
    });                 
})(django.jquery);
```

**url's:**

```
('^/my-app/my-roles-filter-view/(?P<event_id>\d+)/$','my_view'),
```

**views:**

```
def my_view(request,event_id):
    qs = Role.objects.filter(event=event_id).values_list('id')
    return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(qs),mimetype='application/javascript')
```

This just an example using `jquery` you can use any type of `ajax` and achieve this.

Comment: The solution needs java script because when he chooses the `event` in the form the roles must be filtered dynamically(without pushing a button, submitting the whole form and then coming back with the filtered choices) hence `ajax` is the way to go.

Comment: Yes, if you want it to change in the browser when you change the selected event in the widget, then of course you need to use Javascript. Sorry, I misread.

Answer (score 11):

You probably want something along the lines of:

```
class InviteAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        self.instance = obj # Capture instance before the form gets generated   
        return super(InviteAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj=obj, **kwargs)

    def formfield_for_manytomany(self, db_field, request=None, **kwargs):
        if db_field.name == 'role' and self.instance:
            # restrict role queryset to those related to this instance:         
            kwargs['queryset'] = self.instance.event.roles.all()
        return super(InviteAdmin, self).formfield_for_manytomany(
            db_field, request=request, **kwargs)
```

[Django documentation for `formfield_for_manytomany`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.formfield_for_manytomany)

Comment: The question clearly says "how can I only show the roles associated with the event I've **selected** in the **change form**" That is definitely to be done dynamical (ajax). Your solution is static.

Comment: Ah, I missed that detail, thanks. I wouldn't necessarily call this a *static* solution as it varies based on the object loaded and event selected in the database, but I think you're right this doesn't solve the problem *actually* being presented :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide a custom [`formfield_for_foreignkey`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.formfield_for_foreignkey) method in your admin class for the model.

This example (from the documentation that I linked), should get you started:

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        if db_field.name == "car":
            kwargs["queryset"] = Car.objects.filter(owner=request.user)
        return super(MyModelAdmin, self).formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)
```

Comment: This will be done at load time and its not dynamic. I believe that the `choices` must be `filtered` dynamically. That`s what the question seems to about.

Comment: @Pannu: No, this is actually close to the correct solution, but to solve this particular problem you need access to the Invite instance in question.

Answer (score 1):

I believe there are two ways of solving this:

1. ajax method as described by @Pannu
2. non-ajax method which can be achieved by moving `event` field outside of change form (which means that there would be another form to change `event`) and filtering `roles` based on current `event`. I had to solve similar problem recently with limiting available options based on belonging of an object to specific site. Here is a description and code, if you are interested: http://source.mihelac.org/2011/09/8/django-sites-ext/