# How to filter a dropdownlist in Django's admin when a selection is made on another dropdownlist

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-grappelli

I have two dropdownlists in a Django admin site. For example, I have SelectCountry and SelectRegion. Region has a foreignkey relationship to Country. How do I ensure that when a Country is selected, the Regions are filtered based on that Country?

N.B: I am using django-grappelli for my admin backend as well.

Any ideas will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: There is no particularly easy way to this as far as I know. You could use javascript; when a country is selected, asynchronously call the server, retrieving a list of regions for the selected country and populate the second list with. This will require messing with django templates etc.

Comment: @pastylegs - thank you for the response. I was hoping that there was a default way to handle this as I do not wish to (nor do I have much experience with) overriding templates and default Django js implementations.

Comment: Consider using [autocompletion](https://code.google.com/p/django-autocomplete/) instead of dynamic filtering.

Comment: You might find some useful ideas here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9677832/284164

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1914358/django-chain-select

Answer (score 8):

As DrMeers hints at, use [django-smart-selects](https://github.com/digi604/django-smart-selects). No point in re-inventing the wheel.

Comment: django-smart-selects has recently become unmantained. Any alternatives?